# Jackson and schema generation for Deduction-Based Polymorphism

Tags: java, json, jackson, polymorphism, jsonschema

StackOverflow.
I have a tricky task and I can't find a solution.

I'm using Jackson to create JSON AND JSON schema out of java classes with annotations.
I have a JSON property of some abstract type (for example, "AbstractType") inside my java class.
Also, I have several AbstractType implementations that can be used as this JSON property (i.e. in this field of type AbstractType).

To generate a JSON I'm using Deduction-Based Polymorphism (@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.DEDUCTION)) and it works fine.
But I can't find any solutions (even as a workaround) to show fields with inheritance inside a JSON schema.

I've tried to find examples of:

- Override JSON property class in runtime (replace AbstractType by implementation in the schema generation process)
- generate a "oneOf" block instead of a field with the abstract type
- enable something somewhere to do it out-of-the-box
- replace Jackson with something else?
- insert JSON property of the proper type in runtime (like MixIn but with totally new JSON property, not just with annotation overriding)

Does anyone have any examples/hints/ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Additional info:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TypeImpl1.class, name = "type1"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TypeImpl2.class, name = "type2")
})
public abstract class AbstractType {
}

public class TypeImpl1 extends AbstractType {
    @JsonProperty("value")
    public Integer value = 10;
}

public class TypeImpl2 extends AbstractType {
    @JsonProperty("text")
    public String text = "test";
}

public class Container {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name = "test";
    @JsonProperty("field")
    public AbstractType field;
}
```

[image: example code with incomplete schema]

Comment: Please show an example of some classes, the generated schema you'd expect, and what you actually get.

Comment: @tgdavies, I've added the picture to describe it.

Comment: @JaVanna perhaps raise an issue for this on my jsonschema generator library and we can take a look together: https://github.com/victools/jsonschema-generator/issues

Answer (score 0):

Since the Jackson schema generation module is not being actively maintained at the moment, it may be a good idea to look for an alternative, e.g.

- https://github.com/victools/jsonschema-generator
- https://github.com/mbknor/mbknor-jackson-jsonSchema

> Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of the `victools` JSON Schema Generator.

With the `victools`:`jsonschema-generator`, this basic configuration should get you in the right direction:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SchemaGeneratorConfigBuilder configBuilder = new SchemaGeneratorConfigBuilder(
            SchemaVersion.DRAFT_2019_09, OptionPreset.PLAIN_JSON);
    configBuilder.with(new JacksonModule());
    SchemaGenerator generator = new SchemaGenerator(configBuilder.build());
    JsonNode jsonSchema = generator.generateSchema(Container.class);

    System.out.println(jsonSchema.toPrettyString());
}
```

The produced schema looks like this:

```json
{
  "$schema" : "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "field" : {
      "anyOf" : [ {
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "value" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          }
        }
      }, {
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "text" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      } ]
    },
    "name" : {
      "type" : "string"
    }
  }
}
```